# Can I spatially join on a column other than geometry on Python Geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

In a `GeoDataFrame` I have a column with the geometry of the polygons (`Polygon` objects), and another one with `Point` objects, representing the centroid of the polygons. Now, what I want to do is to be able to join spatially on the centroid column, for example, instead of doing

```
test = gpd.sjoin(M, Gsq, op="within")
```

I could do something like

```
test = gpd.sjoin(M["centroid"], Gsq, op="within")
```

So far, `sjoin` works if I overwrite the complete geometry field with the centroid, but that's too ugly. So, any way I can join on a given column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](http://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html) of the `geopandas.sjoin` command, there is no option to select a different column as the geometry for the operation.

However, you can have two columns with geometry data in your geodataframe (for example `geometry_pg` for the polygon geometry and `geometry_pt` for the centroid point geometry.  Then you can set the "active" geometry of the geodataframe to one or the other column.  That way you can do the spatial join without discarding any data.  It's easy to identify what geometry is active at any moment too.  For how to do it, just check the official [documentation](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#geodataframe) of the geodataframe, it's clear and it has a simple example.

Hope it helps.